# how to run shell commands in applescript

Tags: applescript, command-line

I have 100 files in a folder.
I need to get the 5 files that have the word `main` in the filename.
How do I do this in Applescript?

Here is something I found that does not work:

```
set search_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:shawnbrady:Dropbox:Audio:Features:SAL350 Ruiz, Luis NPR:Audio"

set foundItems to (do shell script "find " & my search_folder's POSIX path's quoted form & " -name 'main' ")'s paragraphs
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean: do you get an error message (which one), is `foundItems` empty afterwards, something else?

Comment: You are searching for the name `main`, not a name containing `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Says here in the title you want to do it using shell commands, but have you tried something like this, which is AppleScript?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set h to home as alias
    set mn to the name of every file of folder (h & "Dropbox:Audio:Features:SAL350 Ruiz, Luis NPR:Audio:" as string) whose name contains "main"
    return mn
end tell
```

If you are looking for your search results as UNIX pathnames, try this form.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set h to home as alias
end tell

do shell script ("find " & POSIX path of (alias (h & "Dropbox:Audio:Features:SAL350 Ruiz, Luis NPR:Audio:" as string)) & " -name \"*main*\"" as string)
```

Does that help?